# Delete Row After Counting Number of Columns In Text File

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I need to dynamically delete a line after counting the number of columns in it. For instance, if the number of columns in the line is less than `X`, delete the entire line. I have a text file that contains 100+ lines.

Here's what I have so far, which counts the total number of columns in each line of the text file...

**Text Sample:**

```
KGAI 2 2 40 50 50 98 75 10 35 40 15 25 15 55
KGED 3 3 15 25 20 60 60 20 50 25 15 25 20 40
KGFL 1 10 3 4 3 85 25
KGHG        15 20 40 20 20 20 20
KGKJ 20 80 25 20 25 97 50 20 60 45 30 30 25 30
KGNR 2 30 4 5 5 25 90 10 35 15 15 15 10 20
KGON 1 1 20 10 5 85 65 5 20 30 15 10 15 25
KGTB
KHEF 2 2 20 30 50 98 60 10 30 25 10 15 10 45
```

**Code:**

```
cat text_data | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "};{print NF}'
```

**Output:**

```
15
15
8
8
15
15
15
1
15
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Probably `awk 'NF>X'` is enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it the other way round: just print those that have at least X columns:

```
awk -v cols=5 'NF>=cols' file
```

That is, set the variable `cols` to the value of minimum amount of cols you want the line to have. Whenever it is true, the line will be printed.

In this case it returns:

```
KGAI 2 2 40 50 50 98 75 10 35 40 15 25 15 55
KGED 3 3 15 25 20 60 60 20 50 25 15 25 20 40
KGFL 1 10 3 4 3 85 25
KGHG        15 20 40 20 20 20 20
KGKJ 20 80 25 20 25 97 50 20 60 45 30 30 25 30
KGNR 2 30 4 5 5 25 90 10 35 15 15 15 10 20
KGON 1 1 20 10 5 85 65 5 20 30 15 10 15 25
KHEF 2 2 20 30 50 98 60 10 30 25 10 15 10 45
```